# No funciona atributo download

Tags: html, html5

Hice un código para que se puedan descargar imágenes, (etiqueta download dentro de ), pero no funciona ¿que hago?

```
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/230px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" download="Imagen_HTML.png">
    Descargar en PNG
</a>
```

Comment: De las notas de la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a#Atributos): *Este atributo sólo funciona para las políticas de mismo origen (same-origin URLs)* Por lo tanto, a menos que tu página esté alojada directamente en el mismo host, puerto y protocolo que la imagen, el atributo `download` no surtirá efecto alguno. Mi sugerencia es que uses una llamada Ajax. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras pon eso como respuesta

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro listo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a#Atributos) del atributo `download`:

> Este atributo sólo funciona para las políticas de mismo origen (same-origin URLs)

Eso quiere decir, que si el atributo `href` del elemento *anchor* (`<a>`) apunta a una dirección diferente al dominio al que pertenece el documento, el atributo `download` simplemente será ignorado.

Por lo tanto, la única forma en que el atributo `download` funcione, es que tu página esté alojada en el mismo *host*, puerto y protocolo al que pertenece la imagen que deseas descargar.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr que la imagen se descargue, puedes usar una llamada [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), utilizando Javascript y alguna de las tecnologías disponibles para hacerla [`XMLHttpRequest` (`XHR`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [`JQuery Ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), entre otras.

**Ejemplos:**

**HTML**

```html
<a class="downloadLink"
   id="downloadImage"
   data-url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/230px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
   data-type="image/png"
   data-file-name="230px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
  >Descargar en PNG
</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
.downloadLink {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Javascript**

***Usando `XMLHttpRequest`***

```js
const downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadImage');

const onResponse = function(e) {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      const blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: downloadLink.dataset.type});
      let temporalAnchor = document.createElement('a');
      temporalAnchor.style = 'display: none';
      document.body.appendChild(temporalAnchor);
      let localURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      temporalAnchor.href = localURL;
      temporalAnchor.download = downloadLink.dataset.fileName;
      temporalAnchor.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(localURL);
      document.body.removeChild(temporalAnchor);
    } else {
      console.log('Algo salió mal');
    }
  }
}

const doDownload = event => {
  const remoteURL = event.currentTarget.dataset.url;
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', remoteURL, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send(null);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = onResponse;
}

downloadLink.addEventListener('click', doDownload);
```

***Usando `Fetch`***:

```js
const downloadLink = document.getElementById('downloadImage');
const doDownload = event => {
  const remoteURL = event.currentTarget.dataset.url;
  fetch(remoteURL)
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok) {
      response.blob()
      .then(blob => {
        let localURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let temporalAnchor = document.createElement('a');
        temporalAnchor.style = 'display: none';
        document.body.appendChild(temporalAnchor);
        temporalAnchor.href = localURL;
        temporalAnchor.download = downloadLink.dataset.fileName;
        temporalAnchor.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(localURL);
        document.body.removeChild(temporalAnchor);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Algo salió mal');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message);
  });
}

downloadLink.addEventListener('click', doDownload);
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.